# XSLT java functions in curly braces

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am learning XSLT and I see some codes like the following:

```
  <node id="{java:next($idgen)}:state" pred="should" mood="dcl">
```

where `next` is a java function. What are the curly braces used for?

Besides I am quite confused at how java functions are called in XSLT. In my sample code, XSLT just calls java functions like above without specifying the location of the java class file, even the class name is not specified.

Comment: This xslt code  sample works ?. Besides, your sample doesn't show xslt instructions.

Comment: "*XSLT just calls java functions like above without specifying the location of the java class file, even the class name is not specified.*" Are you sure about that? You only show us a snippet of the code - I suspect there's more.

Comment: Thanks everyone, problem solved! And the above code is not all the code, obviously. The original code uses xalan as the processor.

Comment: The prefix "java" is probably bound to a namespace URI that identifies the class name. The precise conventions vary from one XSLT processor to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the curly braces used for?

The curly braces have nothing to do with Java. They indicate to the processor that the contents are to be evaluated as an *expression* - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#attribute-value-templates

> Besides I am quite confused at how java functions are called in XSLT.

That depends on your specific processor. Calling Java functions is not part of the XSLT standard, and only some processors support it as an extension.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown a [literal result element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#literal-result-element) with an [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template) where the XPath expression inside the attribute value template uses some [XSLT processor specific mechanism to call a Java method](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html#java-namespace) of the variable `$idgen`.